# How can I optimize RecyclerView loading when using Android Room database and Paging 3 library?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I'm building a chat application. I am using the Android room database and Paging 3 lib. now while I am loading the chats in the chat details recyclerview. It is taking a long to load for the first time.

follow this screen record [video](https://artixdevelopment.site/api/Easysent/api/Attachment/1684910945_Record_2023-05-24-12-17-00_77aadcb06fa1eaa67d9dda3e35d78e7f.mp4)

I am using it in the activity class

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_chat_details);
        binding = ActivityGroupChatDetailsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        application = getApplication();
        activity = this;
        context = this;
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");



        mainToolbarBinding = MainToolbarBinding.bind(binding.toolbar.getRoot());
        mainToolbarBinding.back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mainToolbarBinding.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mainToolbarBinding.menuMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        groups_viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Groups_ViewModel.class);
        userVewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserVewModel.class);
        groups_chat_viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Groups_chat_ViewModel.class);



        GroupChatNewAdapter adapter = new GroupChatNewAdapter(handler,userVewModel,groups_chat_viewModel);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
        binding.recycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        binding.recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        binding.recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        binding.recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        groups_chat_viewModel.getMessageBy_paging(id,false).observe(this, new Observer<PagingData<Group_Chat>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagingData<Group_Chat> group_chats) {
                adapter.submitData(getLifecycle(), group_chats);
            }
        });


    }
```

And in the adapter

```
public class GroupChatNewAdapter extends PagingDataAdapter<Group_Chat, GroupChatNewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Handler handler;
String my_id;
    UserVewModel userVewModel;
    Groups_chat_ViewModel groups_chat_viewModel;

    public GroupChatNewAdapter( Handler handler,UserVewModel userVewModel, Groups_chat_ViewModel groups_chat_viewModel) {
        super(Diff_async);
        this.handler = handler;
        this.groups_chat_viewModel = groups_chat_viewModel;
        this.userVewModel = userVewModel;
        my_id = PreferenceFile.getUser().getUser().getId();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Group_Chat> Diff_async = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Group_Chat>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Group_Chat oldItem, @NonNull Group_Chat newItem) {
            Log.e("TAG", "submitData: "+"areItemsTheSame");
            boolean b = oldItem.getRid() == newItem.getRid();
            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Group_Chat oldItem, @NonNull Group_Chat newItem) {
            Log.e("TAG", "submitData: "+"areContentsTheSame");
            boolean b = oldItem.getIsDeleted().equalsIgnoreCase(newItem.getIsDeleted());
            return b;
        }
    };
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.group_chat_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("SOMNATH", "onBindViewHolder: "+position );
        final String[] sender = {""};
        final String[] sender_id = {""};
        final String[] time = {""};
        final String[] message = {""};
        final String[] type = {""};
        final String[] file_name = {""};
        final String[] is_forowoard = {String.valueOf(false)};

        final Users[] user =new Users[1];

        int total = getItemCount();
        Group_Chat item = getItem(position);
        GroupChatItemBinding binding = holder.binding;

        if (item == null) {
            binding.shimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.nonShimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        else{
            binding.shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            binding.nonShimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    userVewModel.selectUser(item.getSender());
                    time[0] = MethodClass.changeDateFormat2(item.getCreatedAt());
                   sender_id[0] = item.getSender();
                   if (item.getSender().equalsIgnoreCase(my_id)){
                       sender[0] = "you";
                   }else{
                      user[0] =  userVewModel.selectUser(item.getSender());
                      sender[0] = user[0].getName();
                   }
                   type[0] = item.getType();
                   message[0] = item.getMessage();

                   if (!item.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("T") && item.getAttachment() != null && !item.getAttachment().equals("null")){
                       file_name[0] = item.getAttachment();
                   }
                   is_forowoard[0] = item.getReplayOf();
                   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           if (item.getSender().equalsIgnoreCase(my_id)){
                              binding.messageMe.setText(message[0]);
                              binding.timeMe.setText(time[0]);
                               binding.shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               binding.nonShimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               binding.chatMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           }else{
                               binding.messageYou.setText(message[0]);
                               binding.timeYou.setText(time[0]);
                               binding.sender.setText(user[0].getName());
                               binding.shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               binding.nonShimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               binding.chatYou.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           }
                       }
                   });

                }
            }).start();
        }







    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        GroupChatItemBinding binding ;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = GroupChatItemBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

in debug I see that the viewholder is creating for all item in list then the list is showing in recyclkerview . But idealy the last some item holder should create as i have used

```
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

but some how its not happening, please help me out

Comment: I would start by getting rid of the stacked Thread calls inside the `onBindViewHolder`. Just run the code directly instead of running it inside runnables.

Comment: But will it be convenient to use that heavy operation inside the adapter?

Comment: It's using the same handler for all view holders, that is your biggest bottleneck, and creating a new thread for each of them on top of that only makes it worse. it doesn't seem like much work is being done to warrant such extreme thread offloading, but if you notice some performance impact you can prepare the view holder data outside, in the adapter for example, or in the activity before feeding the adapter with the data.